# Maui ContentPage Handler is null when page first loads

Tags: maui

I have a base class that I use for all of my pages that is derived from the `ContentPage` class. In there I have several services that will be needed on many of the different pages, which is why I decided to put them into a base class. But the issue that I am facing is that I don't want to use the constructor to resolve the services from the dependency injection container since that is a hassle to do for each page as there will likely be upwards of 10 to 15 services, also the `AppShell` flyout navigation gets mad when I do that because it says that there isn't a default constructor for that page so it can't create it, or something along those lines. So as I understand it, I should be able to resolve my dependencies by calling the method `ContentPage.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<T>();` I would do this in my base class default constructor and that should take care of it. Except that the `Handler` is null on the first time the page loads and is presented to the user. If I call this method in the `OnAppearing()` lifecycle method then it is null, but if I navigate away from that page and then go back to it, then the `Handler` has a value. How can I ensure that this object has a value the first time the page is presented instead of forcing my users to navigate away and then come back.

I have tried awaiting in a loop for up to 15 seconds in the `OnAppearing()` method and the `Handler` still doesn't have a value until after the page is presented for a second time. I haven't found much in the documentation about this, other than that it mentions that the `Handler` can be null, but doesn't offer any explanation as to why or how to handle it. I have only tried this on Android as I am on a Windows machine, and am only targeting Android and iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method named `OnHandlerChanged` in the ContentPage. And in this method. The handler will have the instance. The handler will not initialize when the OnAppearing method called.

So you can get the instance of the Handler in the ContentPage's **OnHandlerChanged** method. Such as:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
   base.OnHandlerChanged();
   var handler = this.Handler;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked perfectly. For anybody else that is building an app this same way, in my base page I override this method, and then I made another method called `protected virtual void OnServicesInitialized()`. Then from the `OnHandlerChanged` method I call my method that resolves my dependencies, and at the end of that method I raise the `OnServicesInitialized` method. This will provide a lifecycle method that will always get fired after the dependency services are resolved.

Comment: I think the cleaner approach is to use Dependency Injection, injecting the services required directly in the constructor of the view model. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection